# Should a device stay connected to a computer to be able to test an app with Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

When you test your app on your iPhone through Xcode, does it require your phone staying connected to the computer, or can you install it and disconnect it with the app still be installed on the phone?

If the answer is that you must leave it connected while testing, what is another way to install the app to leave on the phone and test while not connected to the computer?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is **possible** to disconnect the device and use the app that way.

However, in our case, connectivity means verbose debugging and more via Xcode, so it is highly recommended to debug an app while being connected.

Answer (score 1):

> or can you install it and disconnect it and the app still be installed on the phone?

Correct. So, you build-and-run onto the device and then quit the app. Then disconnect the device from the computer, and launch the app whenever and wherever you like from Springboard in the normal way.

(In fact, there are some kinds of test where this is the *only* way you can test. For example, what if you want to test an app that requires you to travel with the phone?)

The app in this form will expire after a few days but you can just repeat the procedure to get it going again.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to quit the app.  You can just unplug and go!  Xcode will complain though.

Comment: @i_am_jorf That behavior can cause crashes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862458/all-apps-crash-upon-disconnect), and why yank Xcode's chain?

Comment: Sometimes you just gotta go!